# how to make double angled edge that comes to a point in css

Tags: html, css

I've seen a million tutorials on how to make a slanted edge like in [this article](https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms/) for example.

but I cannot seem to find any information on how I would be able to create a div that looks like this...

[image]

a double slanted edge that comes to a point.. now I experimented a bit with using an svg image at the bottom of the div but it just wouldnt work properly.. any idea how I can recreate this??

I've seen something similar which required the user of a clip-path, but I need to support IE etc..

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did a feeble attempt to recreate the same div with a double-slanted edge using before and after pseudo elements. You just have to tweak the rotation, top and left values to match your design.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height:100%;  
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(75deg);
}

div:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  height:100%;  
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-75deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I'm not sure if this is the design that you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplishable with just the `border` property of a second div, which would help with compatibility of older browsers (if you need to support older versions of IE which don't support pseudo-elements, or even current versions, which don't support use of `em` units on pseudo-elements)

The CSS

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
#chevron {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
#second {
  width: 0px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50vw solid blue;
  border-left: 50vw solid blue;
  border-bottom: 50px solid blue;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div id='chevron'></div>
<div id='second'></div>
```

[See this CodePen](https://codepen.io/the_Northway/pen/WYKKBw?editors=1100) for a result.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `linear-gradient`s:

```css
body {
  background:
    linear-gradient(10deg, transparent 45%, #fff 45%) 0 0 / 50vw 50vh,
    linear-gradient(-10deg, transparent 45%, #fff 45%) 100% 0 / 50vw 50vh,
    linear-gradient(180deg, #cde, #eee 70%) 0 0 / 100vw 100vh;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```